# PHP socket, "first will be used" - what will happen to the others?

Tags: php, sockets

In the `socket_accept()` documentation, it says that "the first connection will be used", what does this mean? What will happen to the other connections?

I ask since I saw code examples which accept multiple connections in a loop, without setting the mode to unblocking using `socket_set_nonblock()`

> After the socket socket has been created using socket_create(), bound
> to a name with socket_bind(), and told to listen for connections with
> socket_listen(), this function will accept incoming connections on
> that socket. Once a successful connection is made, a new Socket
> instance is returned, which may be used for communication. ***If there
> are multiple connections queued on the socket, the first will be used.***
> If there are no pending connections, socket_accept() will block until
> a connection becomes present. If socket has been made non-blocking
> using socket_set_blocking() or socket_set_nonblock(), false will be
> returned.

Comment: The extra incoming connections are left in the queue to be accepted later. It's a FIFO. `socket_accept` like all the socket function family in PHP are simply wrappers around the POSIX socket functions. For more exacting documentation see: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/accept.2.html

Comment: Examples that are using blocking reads/writes can usually only service one connection at a time unless they are making use of `select` and the protocol is well defined with message boundaries. Extra connections are just left waiting to be accepted.

Comment: @Geoffrey Thanks. As to the examples, that's the confusing part - if they are accepted later, what is happening to the first connections? they are on hold? i'll read the link..

Comment: Yes, they are on hold. Each socket can have a backlog of connections, how long this backlog is can be configured.